# Using jQuery live() to initialize plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQuery, what's the best way to automatically initialize a plugin on all current and future elements of a specific class?

For example, say I want all `<input type="text" class="datepicker" />` elements to have the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) plugin, including any I might create at runtime.

Essentially, I want to do something like this:

```
$('.datepicker').live('create', function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

But, of course, there isn't a *create* event I can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) for this, reports of it's death due to `.live()` have been greatly exaggerated :)

`.live()` listens for event to bubble so it serves a slightly different purpose.  With `.livequery()` you'd achieve what you want like this:

```
$('.datepicker').livequery(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

This will run on **current and future** `.datepicker` elements.

Comment: is it possible to do with .live() ?

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand you are after creating a custom even. which is like this:

```
$('.datepicker').bind('foo', { 'bar'  : 'bam'  }, function(e) 

  { 

    $(this).datepicker(); 

  });   

$('.datepicker').trigger('foo');
```

hope this helps