# How to trigger a function when new elements are dynamically loaded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have elements being loaded onto the page via **Script A.** [which is old school JavaScript](http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.infinitescrollfortumblr.js)

**[Script B](http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js)** does things to these elements.

**Script B** works on the elements *initially* loaded, but when **Script A** loads new elements, **Script B** doesn't know about it.

Live, delegate and bind won't work as **Script Bs** function is a custom event.

And I'm wondering, surely there is a general function in jQuery which just wakes up and says *some ajax just happpened*. Then all I'd need to do is repeat **Script Bs** function.

---

That's the abstract. I don;t really want to give more code as I don't think it helps. To give you an idea of what I want to achieve, Script A is a JavaScript infinite scroll for Tumblr. Script B is fading images in as they enter the viewport. [It works](http://syndex.me), but only with the first set of images conventionally loaded.

Been stuck on this for four hours and not even close to figuring it out.

---

**EDIT**
Using livequery plugin like so does not work, but it seems tantilising (!) :-/ Maybe it just needs a tweek?

```
$('.theImage').livequery(function() { //.theImage being the dynamically loaded divs
$(this).waypoint(function() { //waypoint being Script B which fades in .theImage
   $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
});
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627972/using-jquery-live-to-initialize-plugins

Comment: what about the success callback function for $.ajax? couldn't you call script b's function in there?

Comment: Hmm, i'm realising it might not be 'ajax' that it uses: http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/jquery.infinitescrollfortumblr.js Script A is actually javascript. Will it be recognised as ajax?

Comment: @RGBK: Javascript and AJAX are orthogonal. That file contains Javascript code that makes an AJAX request in its functions.

Comment: So you reckon thats the way to go? ajaxSuccess is still a jquery fn, not a javascript one right? Will my jquery script be able to listen to ajax events from another file?

Comment: @RGBK: Yes, the script will be able to listen to ajax events from other files.

Comment: @RGBK: jquery.infinitescrollfortumblr.js uses Ajax.  The function at line 100 in that file is where the ajax call is made.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajaxsuccess this works. But if I use this exact setup i get no response. I just dont understand how that could be if there is ajax happening in Script A?

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to re-call script B everytime an ajax request is completed:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, options) {
  // The code here will be called every time
  // an ajax request has completed successfully.
  // Your code may assume that the DOM has been updated.
});
```

Comment: Hi Alfred thanks for replying, there is a discussion above related to this method.

Comment: There is also this method (same question but phrased differently) I'm wondering which method will work best? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910520/how-to-bind-a-custom-event-to-elements-loaded-on-the-fly-from-another-script

Comment: I've pasted a classic ajaxsuccess straight from jqueries sample page. It doesn't notice the ajax unfortunately. Would be really gratefull if you could check it out.

Comment: This just isn't valid answer right now. If ajaxsucess was able to see javascript in other files or on other activity on the document and line 100 in the javascript is a vaild ajax event, i would have had console logs in my test, which leads me to believe this function only happens in it's own scope.